# Processing Java Error: The nested type (Node) cannot hide an enclosing type

Tags: java, compiler-errors, processing

I've looked up this error before, but mainly it's just people that have two class declarations.

I've been searching for hours to find some help but I can't find anything! My only other guess at what is wrong is that it's something to do with the public/private attributes. But that's just a guess!

So I'm not sure what is wrong with my code to cause this, the code is:

```
class Node
{
    //Variables
    private String id;
    private PVector position;
    private Float radius;
    private int headerHeight;
    private String headerText;

    //Needs var holding node links!!

    //Constructor
    public Node(String _id, int _x, int _y, Float _radius)
    {
        id = _id;
        position = new PVector(_x, _y);
        radius = _radius;

        headerHeight = 20;
        headerText = "";
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public String getID()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String _id)
    {
        id = _id;
    }

    public PVector getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(PVector _position)
    {
        position = _position;
    }

    public Float getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(Float _radius)
    {
        radius = _radius;
    }

    public int getHeaderHeight()
    {
        return headerHeight;
    }

    public void setHeaderHeight(int _height)
    {
        headerHeight = _height;
    }

    public String getHeaderText()
    {
        return headerText;
    }

    public void setHeaderText(String _headerText)
    {
        headerText = _headerText;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's your error coming from?

Comment: have you declared this class Node into another class named Node?

Comment: The error highlights "class Node" at the top. 

I have no other declaration of Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your **tab** or **sketch** name is the same as program's inner class name. Change the name of your tab/sketch and you'll be fine.

---

Rename your **sketch** (`foo.pde`) which is also the name of the **tab** to something other than the class name.  The main sketch in processing cannot have a nested class with the same name, other sketches (other tabs) can have classes that are the same name as the tab.

Comment: The file itself is called Node.pde, is that the problem?

Comment: Probably, try to use another name for your sketch.

Comment: All my other classes are saved in the same way though.

Comment: Use different names for other tabs as well, otherwise you'll end up with the same error message.

Comment: EDIT: I made a try and it seems that the only name you must change is the sketch name. Tab names other than the first have no consequences in the Java translation.